# Unable to transfer files from laptop to USB due to permission error

Tags: permissions, filesystem

I am unable to transfer file from my system with Ubuntu 11.10 OS to a USB drivee (Hp 16GB).
When I copy files from system and try to paste in USB the paste option gets disable. But the reverse is possible. Any solution for this?

Comment: How is the USB drive formatted? and the output of `mount`

Answer (score 0):

What's the format of you USB drive e.g vfat, ext*? and are you trying to paste into a particular folder (you might not have write permission on that folder).

To do the following tasks, you will need to open a xterm window (usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> starts the terminal).

You can check your file permissions of that usb drive using:
`ls -l /media/usb_drive/`. Look for the folder you want to paste into to see if you have write permission i.e `rwx-rwx-rwx username groupname /media/usb_drive/folder`.

To change a folder's permission thus adding write permissions use:

```
sudo chmod +w /media/usb_drive/folder
```

Try to copy and paste files into you `usb_drive/folder` again.